# How to iterate over pairs of columns in a data table to create a new column in R

Tags: r, loops, paste, complex-numbers

I currently have data of complex numbers in the form:

```
r1,i1,r2,i2,...
-1.74550E-0001,5.04828E-0002,7.37643E-0002,-1.70416E-0001,...
...
```

And wish to make new columns from the modulus of these complex numbers, I attempted to do this via:

```
data=read.table("umatrix.txt", header=T, sep=",")

for (i in 1:43){
  data$paste("m",toString(i), sep = "") = sqrt((data$paste("r",toString(i), sep = "")^2)+(data$paste("i",toString(i), sep = "")^2))
  }
```

But this obtains the error:

> Error: attempt to apply non-function

Presumably because paste() cannot be used in this manner with the datatable$column syntax. How would one achieve this?

EDIT: Nevermind, fixed using the other syntax, as follows:

```
for (i in 1:43){
    data[1:43,paste("m",toString(i), sep = "")] = sqrt((data[1:43,paste("r",toString(i), sep = "")]^2)+(data[1:43,paste("i",toString(i), sep = "")]^2))
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to fully parse this at the moment, but you can try indexing via `[` intead of `$`.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works. Strange there's such a difference.

Comment: it's hard to search for `[[` and `$` on StackOverflow, but there have been a number of different recent questions along these lines -- almost a FAQ.

Comment: In regard to your data structure, I would put all the real and imaginary parts in a single column, maybe with an additional identification column. Then there is no need for the loop, you can just use `mod = with(data, sqrt(r^2) + (i^2))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract a column you can either use:

```
dat$column
```

or:

```
dat["column",] # Notice the "
```

The outcome of `paste` is a string, therefore you need to use the second form, i.e.:

```
dat[paste(...),]
```

When you use the first form like you did:

```
dat$paste(...)
```

R is looking for a function called `dat$paste`, which does not exists resulting in the error.

Note that `dat$column` is actually equal to `dat[["column"]]`. This form extracts the column as a vector. Alternatively, the `dat["column",]` form yields not a vector, but a `data.frame` with one column. This last form can thus also be used to extract multiple columns: `dat[c("a","b"),]`